# Exporting python list to csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv, export-to-csv

I have the below list called tes and I need to store it in csv format.

```
tes=[('branch=cse\\',{'name':['abc'],'sex':['male']}),('branch=ece\\',{'name':['def']})]
```

when the list have all the values,my code works good but if some value is missing in the list, I get KeyError. I have attached my code below. Can someone provide me with a better option ?

```py
import csv
tes=[('branch=cse\\',{'name':['abc'],'sex':['male']}),('branch=ece\\',{'name':['def']})]
with open('check.csv','w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['givenName','sex']
    writer=csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for i in tes:
        writer.writerow({'givenName': i[1]['name'], 'sex': i[1]['sex']})
```

Comment: `i[1].get('sex', "default value")` - if there is no `['sex']` then it returns `"default value"` instead of `KeyError`

Comment: @furas where should I mention this? can you please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: `writer.writerow({'givenName': i[1].get('name', 'unknown'), 'sex': i[1].get('sex', 'male?')})`

Comment: @furas .get method worked.Thank you soo much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `i[1].get('sex', "default value")`. If there is no key `['sex']` then it returns `"default value"` instead of `KeyError`

```
writer.writerow({'givenName': i[1].get('name', 'unknown'), 'sex': i[1].get('sex', 'male?')})
```